# How do I use grouping using Collection View MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, grouping, collectionview

I'm fairly new to MVVM, and I have recently started a project cleaning up my codebehind and bit by bit I am moving everything to Model and ViewModel.

My problem is, now, how do you use grouping using Collection View without any code behind? I thought I had figured it out, after reading answers to similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but I still can't get it to work. Probably a silly mistake, but I would be very grateful if somebody could have a look at my code and let me know what they think. All feedback is great feedback, I really want to become a good programmer :)

The list is btw of the type ObservableCollection in the Menu class.

```
             <CollectionViewSource x:Key="foods" Source="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Category"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>




 <ListBox x:Name="selectedMenuItem" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource foods}}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                                    <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default"/>
                                </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            </ListBox>




           private CollectionViewSource _items;
    private Menu _menu = new Menu();

    public ICollectionView Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new CollectionViewSource {Source = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(_menu.MyMenu)};
            }

            return _items.View;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your problem is that data doesn't show up in your ListBox? Try programmatically adding your groupings to `_items` and binding your ListBox.ItemsSource directly to `Items`:

```
public ICollectionView Items 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if (_items == null) 
        { 
            _items = new CollectionViewSource {Source = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(_menu.MyMenu)}; 
            _items.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
        } 

        return _items.View; 
    } 
}

<ListBox x:Name="selectedMenuItem" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"       
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">       
                                <ListBox.GroupStyle>       
                                    <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default"/>       
                                </ListBox.GroupStyle>       
                            </ListBox>
```

You can then do away with the `foods` resource, assuming I haven't boffed my code.

Comment: _items.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category")); --> Did the trick! (plus just using Binding Items, I tried that earlier, but did not add the property description in ViewModel) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without requiring a dispatcher object in my viewmodel?